# Common way to generate finite geometric series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, series

Suppose I have some number `a`, and I want to get vector `[ 1 , a , a^2 , ... , a^N ]`. I use `[ 1 , cumprod( a * ones( 1 , N - 1 ) ) ]` code. What is the best (and propably efficient) way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about `a.^[0:N]` ?

Comment: I am afraid that it will need O(N^2) products, while cumprod needs only O(N) products

Comment: Definitely the most compact way

Comment: @UncleAli: Try profiling both methods. But yeah, it's bound to be slower.

Comment: @Jacob: My way is approx. 2x faster. Nevertheless, it's acceptable because of great readability improvement. Thanks.

Comment: @UncleAli: A couple of things to note... 1) I wouldn't expect `a.^(0:N)` to have O(N^2) dependence, probably more like O(N*logN) since I imagine the exponentiation is done with [a more efficient algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). 2) Don't be too caught off guard if the results of the two different methods aren't *exactly* equal when using floating point values for `a`. Since they use two different underlying algorithms, with different orders of mathematical operations, you may see tiny differences on the order of the floating-point precision.

Answer (score 2):

ThibThib's answer is absolutely correct, but it doesn't generalize very easily if `a` happens to a vector. So as a starting point:

```
> a= 2
a =  2
> n= 3
n =  3
> a.^[0: n]
ans =
   1   2   4   8
```

Now you could also utilize the built-in function `vander` (although the order is different, but that's easily fixed if needed), to produce:

```
> vander(a, n+ 1)
ans =
   8   4   2   1
```

And with vector valued `a`:

```
> a= [2; 3; 4];
> vander(a, n+ 1)
ans =
   8    4    2    1
  27    9    3    1
  64   16    4    1
```